# Mercurial merge creates new head in subrepos

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I am working on a large project, with a main repository and multiple subrepos, organized like this:

```
main-repo
    sub-a
    sub-b
    sub-c
```

Each person working has one or more named branches of their own.  I am working in a branch that we will call `shastings-dev` and a co-worker has a branch that we will call `coworker-dev`.  (Both of these branches exist in `main-repo`, `sub-a`, and `sub-b`; neither exists in `sub-c` and we are both using someone else's branch for that one.)

My problem is that I can no longer merge changes from `coworker-dev` without creating a new head somehow.  This sequence of commands has the unexpected effect:

```
hg pull
hg branch # prints: shastings-dev
hg merge --tool internal:other coworker-dev
hg commit -m "merge coworker-dev" --subrepos
hg push
```

The `hg push` prints this message:
`abort: push creates new remote head 945a60694252 on branch 'shastings-dev'! (in subrepo sub-a)`

---

EDIT -- I am breaking the question here and putting the answer.  The rest of the question will be left intact below for anyone who is really interested in all the details.

The solution: for each subrepo that needed a merge, change directory to the subrepo and follow these steps:

```
hg update --clean shastings-dev
hg merge --tool internal:other coworker-dev
hg commit -m "merge coworker-dev"
hg push
```

(I did this for subrepos `sub-a` and `sub-b`.  For `sub-c` I just ran `hg update correct_branch_name` to make sure that it was at the head as well.)

Then, once each subrepo has been properly updated, return to the containing repo, and:

```
hg commit -m "commit .hgsubstate after merging in subrepos"
hg push
```

As a result of this experience, I am going to adopt a new rule:

***If you have problems with subrepos, always retry the commands in the individual subrepos.***

What confused me was that `hg update --clean` switched all the subrepos, but didn't actually update them.  The heads for the subrepos belonged to a different branch than the one showing with `hg branch`.  As a result, @zerkms's comment was correct: the subrepos actually *were not* on the head and the merge really was creating a new head.

In other words, even if `hg id` shows that the main repo is at the head, that doesn't mean the subrepos updated properly and are also at their respective heads.  Check the subrepos individually to figure out the real state of things.

---

EDIT -- rest of original question is below.
My first thought was that my local copy of the repo was somehow scrambled.  So I cloned an absolutely fresh copy of the repo, verified that `hg pull` didn't bring anything new in and tried the merge/commit/push again.  Same problem.

I have tried doing the merge/commit/push in the subrepo then doing commit in the main repo (to update `.hgsubstate`) and then doing merge/commit/push in the main repo.  No joy.

I have tried using TortoiseHg on Windows to clone the repo, update to branch `shastings-dev`, and then merge/commit/push.  Same problem.

So now my questions:

- Why is a new head being created?  Am I doing something wrong, is there something wrong with my branch, or is this expected behavior?
- What should I do?  Can I eliminate this multiple heads problem, or should I push with `-f` and then close the older of the two heads with `hg commit --close-branch`?
- What bad things might happen if I use `hg push -f`?  My personal rule is "don't do that unless you are a Mercurial expert" and I'm not a Mercurial expert.  (So my actual personal rule is "never use `hg push -f`.")

By the way, I am not working on any files that coworker is working on.  At this time I have only minor differences from `coworker-dev` and I would be willing to totally lose all history on branch `shastings-dev`, as long as I can get a working up-to-date branch with the same name.  (If I lose my changes I am willing to copy the changed files over again.  I just want Mercurial to work as expected again.)

EDIT: I am on a branch head when I do the above.

```
$ hg heads
changeset:   1515:803ea844dc8a
branch:      coworker2-dev
tag:         tip
user:        coworker2
date:        Tue Oct 08 17:33:31 2013 -0700
files:       .hgsubstate
description:
Fixed some stuff in the foo bar.


changeset:   1513:1e76e6a43d83
branch:      coworker-dev
parent:      1509:5e5392aded0a
user:        coworker@place_where_i_work.com
date:        Tue Oct 08 16:44:04 2013 -0700
files:       foo.java bar.java baz.java quux.java
description:
Added more support to the foo bar for release.


changeset:   1422:8705d62db8f2
branch:      shastings-dev
user:        shastings@place_where_i_work.com
date:        Wed Oct 02 21:08:39 2013 -0700
files:       .hgsubstate
description:
Finish adding files

...many others not copied here...
$ hg id
8705d62db8f2 (shastings-dev)

$ hg update --clean shastings-dev
resolving manifests
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

$ hg id
8705d62db8f2 (shastings-dev)

$ hg merge --tool internal:other coworker-dev
...much output not copied here...

$ hg commit -m "merge coworker-dev" --subrepos
...much output not copied here...

$ hg push
pushing to https://path/to/repo/dir/main-repo
pushing subrepo sub-a to https://path/to/repo/dir/sub-a
searching for changes
new remote heads on branch 'shastings-dev'
new remote head 85d8faada6c4
new remote head 90ce145db695
abort: push creates new remote head 85d8faada6c4 on branch 'shastings-dev'! (in subrepo sub-a)
(you should pull and merge or use push -f to force)
```

As I said, when I had problems, I re-cloned everything.  So the status is clean: I have no modified files.

Also, I have one other branch, and I tried the above sequence with the other branch.  It happened again just as described.  So, if anything is wrong, I figure it must be wrong in branch `coworker-dev` and not in my own branches.

Comment: Show `hg id` after merge and commit, right before push attempt. What is the changeset `90ce145db695`? Show `hg in` as well

Comment: `hg log -v -r 90ce145db695`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is a new head being created? Am I doing something wrong, is there something wrong with my branch, or is this expected behavior?

You're not on the branch head, so merge creates another one

```
-- A (you're here) --- B --- C (head #1)
    \
      D (merge, head #2)
```

So you need to make sure you're on the head using `hg id` and `hg heads`. And if no - `hg up`

> What should I do? Can I eliminate this multiple heads problem, or should I push with -f and then close the older of the two heads with hg commit --close-branch?

You should solve the real issue. See the advice above

> What bad things might happen if I use hg push -f? My personal rule is "don't do that unless you are a Mercurial expert" and I'm not a Mercurial expert. (So my actual personal rule is "never use hg push -f.")

My personal rule is - to never use `-f`. After 4 years of experience with mercurial I don't see any good reason to use it at all. What may happen - as soon as there are 2 heads, what would `hg up branchname` do? What would `hg up` do?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  You gave me the push I needed to find the answer, so I'm accepting this as the answer.  I'll put details in the question.

Comment: You shouldn't put the answer in the question as it's confusing (people might think that the accepted answer is the correct answer). You should add it as an actual answer which you can then accept.  If another answer led you to find the correct solution, you can up-vote it to show your appreciation.